How do I display a continuous scale on a plotly Scatterpolar trace?
I have a dataframe containing the azimuths and elevations of multiple GPS satellites. I would like to display this data in a Plotly Scatterpolar plot and colour the trace for each satellite based on one of the other attributes in the file e.g. SNR (Signal to Noise Ratio). I am using plotly graph objects and i can create the plot seemingly ok, but....
1)How can I change the colour scale of the traces?
2) How can I display the legend of the continuous SNR scale?
3) Is it possible to auto generate different symbols for each satellite trace?
The data frame I have looks like this:
PRN,Azimuth,Elevation,SNR
G02,247,23,45
G02,248,24,47
G02,249,25,50
G03,130,45,43
G03,131,46,44
G03,132,47,44
G04,187,60,47
G04,186,59,45
G04,185,57,43

The code I have so far looks like this:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data=r'C:\data\satellites.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data)

fig1 = go.Figure()

# Loop through satellites in file to create a separate trace for each one
for prn in df['PRN'].unique():
    prndf = df.loc[df['PRN'] == prn]

    # Create trace
    fig1.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
        r = prndf['Elevation'],
        theta = prndf['Azimuth'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = dict(color=prndf.SNR),
    ))

fig1.update_layout(
    template=None,
    legend_title_text='PRN Number',
    title=f"Satellite plots",
    font=dict(
        size=18
    ),
    polar = dict(
        radialaxis = dict(range=[90, 0], showticklabels=True, ticks=''),
        angularaxis = dict(showticklabels=True,rotation = 90,direction='clockwise')
    )
)
fig1.show()

Any suggestions for my 3 questions? I have attached an image showing what I have so far with a larger dataset and more satellites. I just need a more visually appealing colour scheme, a suitable legend and symbols.


Just a few updates.
Color scale is set by marker_colorscale. As an alternative you can chose a different named colorscale or declare your own colorscale (e.g. ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'] or [[0, 'red'], [0.75, 'orange'], [1, 'yellow']]).
I set the same color range for all traces to keep the same scale. There are actually three colorbars layered on top of each other but you can't tell because they're all identical. Without setting the same color range you'd notice the layering because they'd all have different numbers.
fig1 = go.Figure()
symbols = ['square', 'circle', 'diamond'] #update symbols as desired
symbol_map = {x:s for x,s in zip(df['PRN'].unique(), symbols)}

# Loop through satellites in file to create a separate trace for each one
for prn in df['PRN'].unique():
    prndf = df.loc[df['PRN'] == prn]
    symb = symbol_map[prn] #declares symbol for trace
    # Create trace
    fig1.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
        r = prndf['Elevation'],
        theta = prndf['Azimuth'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = dict(color=prndf.SNR,
                      colorscale='Earth', #sets colorscale
                      cmin=df['SNR'].min(), #sets color range 
                      cmax=df['SNR'].max(),
                      symbol=symb,
                      size=10,
                      colorbar=dict(title='Colorbar')),#forces creation of colorbar
    ))

fig1.update_layout(
    template=None,
    legend=dict(x=0.8, #moves legend out of the way of colorbar
                title_text='PRN Number'),
    title=f"Satellite plots",
    font=dict(
        size=18
    ),
    polar = dict(
        radialaxis = dict(range=[90, 0], showticklabels=True, ticks=''),
        angularaxis = dict(showticklabels=True,rotation = 90,direction='clockwise')
    )
)
fig1.show()



Excellent answer, many thanks
